# ReactJS creating add modal

Tags: reactjs, redux

I an new in reactjs! I am struggling to implement a modal with 3 field like `name, age, email` and i just lost hope implementing it.
I want to keep the modal in separate file like `form.js` and the modal should appear when i click on `ADD EMPLOYEE` button

this is my `src/components/App.js` file:

```
import React from "react"
import Table from "./table"

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            employees: [
                {
                    name: 'Jhon Doe',
                    age: 18,
                    email: 'something@gmail.com'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Jhon',
                    age: 18,
                    email: 'something@gmail.com'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Doe',
                    age: 25,
                    email: 'something@gmail.com'
                },
                {
                  name: 'Doe',
                  age: 25,
                  email: 'something@gmail.com'
                },
            ],
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">EMPLOYEEAPP</a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Employee</a>
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </div>
              </div>
          </nav>
          <hr/>
              <h1>Employee Information System</h1>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">ADD EMPLOYEE</button>
            <hr/>
            <table className="table table-striped table-dark">
                <Table employees={this.state.employees} />
            </table>


            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

You may notice on above file that there is a button named

```
ADD EMPLOYEE
```

I want when i click on this button, it should open a modal to add employee.

and this is my `src/components/table.js` file

```
import React, {Fragment} from "react"


class Table extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Age</th>
                    <th scope="col">Email</th>
                    <th scope="col">EDIT</th>
                    <th scope="col">DELETE</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {this.props.employees.map((item, index) => (
                    <tr>
                        <td>{item.name}</td>
                        <td>{item.age}</td>
                        <td>{item.email}</td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">EDIT</button></td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">DELETE</button></td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
                </tbody>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default Table;
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this simple thing? It became too hard to implement for me as i am new here. this question may too much amuture too and please pardon me if you think like this

Comment: I would 1) add state that is a boolean that reflects whether or not the modal is open, name it "isModalOpen" or something 2) make is so pressing the button toggles that state 3) add the modal to your JSX in your App.js 4) make it so that modal is only visible if "isModalOpen" is true.

Comment: I just saw your edit, you could easily have another file that has the modal component. Then in App.js, under the table, you could have 

`{isModalOpen && <ModalComponent someProp='foo' />}`